# Deleting specific words in a sentence discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make it so that if someone says 'polls(their question)', then it would extract the question and put it in the embed's title. Only problem is that I dont know how to remove the 'polls' word in their sentence.

So for an example, lets say I said polls who is joe. Then the bot will respond with an embed with the title 'who is joe'. What I want to find out how to get rid of is the 'polls part of the sentence. Heres the code, you dont need to necessarily use the same code but I just need a brief explanation.

````
      joe = message.content
      kar=discord.Embed(title=joe, description="Polls")
      await message.channel.send(embed=kar)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know that your sentence starts with the word `poll`, you can split the sentence into words as such:

```py
words = message.content.split()
```

and get just the words after the word `poll`, by:

```py
polltitle = words[1:]
```

After that, you might want to join the words back to a string, by

```py
polltitle = ' '.join(polltitle)
```

And then you get your polltitle.
For example

```py
message.content = "poll who is joe?"
words = message.content.split()
>> ['poll','who','is','joe?']
polltitle = words[1:]
>> ['who','is','joe?']
polltitle = ' '.join(polltitle)
>> "who is joe?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the message at the `(`

```
message = 'Poll(their question)'
message = message.split('(') # -> ['Poll', 'their question)']
message = message[-1][:-1] # -> 'their question'
```

Edit:
Another way would be to replace `'Poll'` and strip the parentheses:

```
message = 'Poll(their question)'
message = message.replace('Poll', '').strip('()')
```